# img.copy(),img.shape() in OpenCV

Tags: python, visual-studio, function, opencv, wrapper

I tried to use img.copy() function as this,

```
def cv_imcpy(im):
    return list(im.copy())
```

It returned this error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

How can I use img.copy() and img.shape() function in Python?
I'm using OpenCV in Python with VS.NET IDE

Answer (score 1):

If you have read the image into the n-dimensional array im, then im.copy() will simply return a copy of the image which you can store by some other name. The code shown below should make the use of both functions quite clear.

```
import numpy as np
a=[[5,2],[4,3]]
c=np.asarray(a,dtype=float)
b=c.copy()
print c.shape
```

b is a copy of c and the output of shape is 2,2

Answer (score 0):

Needs to call the function `cv_imcpy` by supplying an image as an argument, to check it 
define `cv_imcpy` as below:

```
    def cv_imcpy(im):
        if im is None:
            print("no image passed")
            return()
        else:
            #write your operation/logic here
```